# Transfer ownership of abandoned Google Analytics account

Tags: google-analytics, transfer, ownership

The web team of a new client was fully responsible for the client's Google Analytics account, meaning the client didn't keep records of the account. Now that that web team has gone under we are trying to retrieve the account.

Is it possible to request an account to be transferred to another owner, or alternatively have a full-privileged user added to the account? What steps should I take to resolve this issue with Google?

Comment: This might help you out: http://savvydealer.com/reclaim-your-google-analytics-account/

Answer (score 1):

Not that I am aware of. Google does not provide support at all so transferring an account would likely be impossible.

However, not all is lost. Create a new account, get new code for the website, verify the site, and *Bobs your uncle!*

Comment: And obviously all previous analytics data would be lost. I suppose there really isn't much choice in this situation.

Comment: No. I do always recommend not relying only on Google Analytics. I always tell people to at least install a log analyzer. There are some open source free analyzers that are extremely good. I use SawMill, but that is not open source and is expensive. http://awstats.sourceforge.net/ is free and very popular. So is http://www.webalizer.org/ There are many other options some extremely good. Google Analytics is famous for being inaccurate. I use it of course because Google can tell you things internal to Google.